# Alternative to 'options' in backbone.js 1.1.2

Tags: backbone-views

From my view menuitemdetails.js i'am calling options in app.js - itemDetails

My menuitemdetails.js

```
var MenuItemDetails = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function () {
        var markup = '<div>' +
        '<h1>' + this.options.name + '</h1>' +
        '<p><span class="label">' + this.options.category + '</span></p>' +
        '<img src="photos/' + this.options.imagepath + '" class="img-polaroid" />' +
        '</div>';

        this.$el.html(markup);
        return this;
    }
});
```

My app.js

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "": "list",
        "menu-items/new": "itemForm",
        "menu-items/:item": "itemDetails"
    },

    list: function () {
        $('#app').html('List screen');
    },

    itemDetails: function (item) {
        var view = new MenuItemDetails(
            {
                name: item,
                category: 'Entree',
                imagepath: 'garden-salad.jpg'
            }
        );

        $('#app').html(view.render().el);
    },

    itemForm: function () {
        $('#app').html('New item form');
    }
});

var app = new AppRouter();

$(function () {
    Backbone.history.start();
});
```

Looking forward for an alternative of 'options' because from my view it is not working in backbone.js 1.1.2